# mock function is not being called despite passing jest.fn as a prop

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test the select function of this component, im using

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-giphy-searchbox

I'm using it like this

**GifSection.tsx**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactGiphySearchbox from "react-giphy-searchbox";
import "./style.css";
type GifType = {
  apiKey: string;
  select: (e: any) => void;
};
const GifSection: React.FC<GifType> = (props) => {
  const { apiKey, select } = props;
  return (
    <div data-testid="gif-section">
      <ReactGiphySearchbox
        data-testid="search-box"
        wrapperClassName="gifForm"
        searchFormClassName={{ padding: "20px 0px" }}
        apiKey={apiKey}
        onSelect={(e) => select(e)}
        masonryConfig={[
          { columns: 4, imageWidth: 110, gutter: 5 },
          { mq: "1000px", columns: 4, imageWidth: 120, gutter: 5 },
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
export default GifSection;
```

**GifSection.test.tsx**

```
it("should test onSelect", () => {
    const mockSelect = jest.fn();
    render(
      <GifSection
        apiKey="****************"
        select={mockSelect}
      />
    );
    expect(mockSelect).toBeCalledTimes(1);
});
```

and im getting

> expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalledTimes(expected)
>
> ```
> Expected number of calls: 1
> Received number of calls: 0
> ```

I'm not sure why this is happening, could it be the 3rd party plugin itself ?

For better context when digging deep into the 3rd party component itself

```
  // screen.debug(screen.getByTestId("SearchFormInput"));
  // console.log
  // <input
  //   class="input"
  //   data-testid="SearchFormInput"
  //   name="search"
  //   placeholder="Search for GIFs"
  //   type="text"
  //   value=""
  // />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSelect={(e) => select(e)}` is not fired until a change event is fired. You should fire a `screen.click` event from your testing file.

**API Specific**

Looking a the docs for `react-giphy-searchbox`, `onSelect`: *REQUIRED A callback which is triggered whenever a GIF is selected. It returns a Gif object in the format specified for an image from Giphy's API*. Therefore simply clicking (as I suggested won't work).

You should use `screen.debug` to see what html is being generated and try and select something that way but in all honesty you should not be calling an API when testing. You are basically testing either the GIPHY service which is not your job or that the prop system in React works which is also not your job when testing.

Comment: yeah it didn't work, i tried `fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("SearchFormInput"));`

Comment: I've added further comment

Comment: Also, delete your API key from the example for your own sake 